# theory number, number of solutions, not prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

I have been troubled by this:

$\tau(2^x \times 3^y)=m$

Being $x$, $y$ and $m$ positive integers

Then the number of solutions is $\tau(m)$

I already have done the proof for m prime however cant do it with m not prime, what can I do?

I am stuck with this equation basically:

$(x+1)(y+1)=m$

Comment: Is $\tau$ the number of positive divisors?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is useful to allow $x$ or $y$ to be $0$.

For fixed $m$ the number of solutions of $(x+1)(y+1)=m$ in non-negative integers is then $\tau(m)$. This is because for any $d\gt 0$ such that $d$ divides $m$.  we can let $x+1=d$, and $y+1=m/d$.